# Why are my floated list items stacking?

Tags: html, css

Usually, I can CSS myself out of any corner, but this Friday afternoon issue is getting to me!

[Here is the problem](http://vanquish.websitewelcome.com/~wwwwetd/). Mouse over the menu items  (birthday, wedding, ...) and observe the dropdown.

Originally, I had these list items floating left fine. I've mucked around a lot with the CSS on the rest of the site, and since I checked them again they refused to float next to each other. They just stack up!

It works if I give them an explicit width, but I don't know from the start how wide they will be exactly (generated dynamically).

I'm looking at it on Firefox 3.6.8. The problem also occurs on Safari. I haven't tested any other browsers yet.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing with CSS on a Friday afternoon?!

Comment: @BoltClock Worst time to be bitten by CSS. At least it is not an IE bug. (*shudders*, haven't tested the layout in IE yet)

Comment: @BoltClock Someone is desperate for Copy Editor :P

Comment: Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor do not count tag-only edits. Only Organizer looks at tag edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**attempt #2**

`white-space:nowrap;` does the trick. Set it on container - `#secondary-menu ul li ul`. Now submenu is one long line (tried in firebug).

Pretty handy property, I might use it one day too.

Comment: Ah yep, it would look much nicer if I did indeed want them stacked. But I don't, sorry. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @alex can you clarify what "float next to each other" means? You want them in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Using firebug, I changed the width of `#secondary-menu ul li ul` to 50em and it straightened out...

`#secondary-menu ul li ul`  width appears to be calculated from a containing box somehow.  But 100% of what, the data it contains?  that doesn't make sense.

Try putting a `div` around the `ul` menu to be the `position: absolute`, and then the `ul` can resize inside it...

Comment: I can't give it `50em` because I want the background to only be as wide as it needs to be, not fixed. I might try your second suggestion now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I figured that the set size wouldn't work, but it illustrates what is going wrong.  I think the 100% doesn't do what you want.